# Recursive Bubble Sort in C

Tags: c, sorting, recursion, bubble-sort

I am unable to find the error in the silly recursive bubble-sort code below. Could somebody tell why it is not working correctly? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int b[8] = { -9, 9, 89, 78, 56, 45, 34, 89 };

void print(int n)
{
    int i; 

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d\t", b[i]);

    printf("\n");
}

void rb(int n)
{
    if(n == 0) 
        return;

    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        if (b[i + 1] > b[i])
            j = b[i + 1];

        b[i + 1] = b[i];
        b[i] = j;
    }

    rb(n - 1);
}

int main()
{
    print(8); 
    rb(8); 
    print(8); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The 3 statements that do the swap need to be inside `{...}` so they'll all be governed by the `if`. And the `if` test is backward too if you're aiming to put the numbers in ascending order.

Comment: I question the usefulness of the re-indenting edits, when the original misleading (and generally lousy) indentation was arguably part of the problem in the first place.

Comment: Yes how can I miss brackets...stupid...extemely poor question .

Comment: Just dont downvote because I m unable to delete it.

Comment: This could have been avoided by [always using brackets on if-then](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AlwaysUseBracesOnIfThen). Alternatively you could use a proper IDE that provides correct identation since the error is very clear after nil's edit. @WumpusQ. Wumbley I admit I had to look at the edit history to understand how OP could have missed it with that obvious identation, but I think nil's edit was positive since the error remained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your if statement in the for loop really looks like this below, need to add "{" and "}" around the three lines of code that does the swapping.  Also since j is only used in the swap part of the code.  if you had scoped 'j' inside of the 'if' block.  the compiler would have found this issue.

```
void rb(int n)
{
    if(n==0)
        return;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        if(b[i+1]>b[i]) {
            /* swap the two values and scope j as tightly as possible */
            int j=b[i+1]; 
            b[i+1]=b[i];
            b[i]=j;
        }
    }
    rb(n-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change your function rb() to the code below it works for me, sorting from largest to smallest.

```
void rb(int n)
{
    if(n == 0)
        return;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        if (b[i + 1] > b[i]) {
            int j = b[i + 1];
            b[i + 1] = b[i];
            b[i] = j;
        }
    }
    rb(n - 1);
}
```

Output:

```
-9  9   89  78  56  45  34  89  
89  89  78  56  45  34  9   -9
```

Answer (score 1):

Your for statement needs to be fixed.

```
for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        if (b[i + 1] > b[i]) {
            j = b[i + 1];    
            b[i + 1] = b[i];
            b[i] = j;
        }
    }
```